# Node.js check data base chages with worker

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mongodb

I want to check MySQL table for new records and transfer to mongo db.
How i can do this?

- Create some event listener
- Run some code every 5 minutes

P.S. I know how to connect to database and get/insert records.